# Map a virtual directory to an ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, action, virtual-directory

For our newsletter application, we want to hide our application directory by using a virtual directory on the main website. So for instance, our app is at `app.example.com` and the viewer is at `app.example.com/article/view/id`. We would like to use something like `example.com/newsletter/id` as a link in the newsletter for the public to view. Is this possible? If so, how?

This is so we can hide the structure of the application from the readers so people don't start browsing the structure of our application. Yes, we do have security on the application.

I believe we are on IIS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to write a page that pulled the html from myapp.domain.com to domain.com/app.aspx. We didn't want to mess with the Global file at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directories are just containers for web applications. So a virtual directory corresponds to an ASP.NET (MVC) application. They are mapped to a physical location of the application and belong to a particular web site. When you say `app.example.com` you have already mapped this domain to some web site in IIS, so you could only have sub virtual directories: `app.example.com/app1`, `app.example.com/app2`, ... But if you have a site which is mapped to the `example.com` domain then you could have virtual directories which correspond to `example.com/app1`, `example.com/app2`, ... And of course inside each app you could have routing which corresponds to `controller/action/id`.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if there was anything special to do or not. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at this more. I am confused. Can you clarify this some?

Comment: @Mike Wills, what confuses you? I am not sure in what sense I could clarify this more.

Comment: So I can tell IIS that /article/view/id is /newsletter/id?

Comment: @Mike, why do you want to tell IIS something like this? That's the application responsibility and the way you define your routes in `Global.asax`, isn't it? Of course there are ISAPI extensions available for IIS which would allow you to rewrite requests but quite honestly you have the ASP.NET MVC routing at your disposal, so why would you want to do some stuff like this?

Comment: Look at my original question? I'll clarify it some.

Comment: @Mike, I am sorry I really don't get it. Can't you just tweak your routes to reflect your needs of urls? I mean, what prevents you from having the following route: `"newsletter/{id}"` where you would provide `controller="article"` and `action="view"` as default route values? Hope someone gets it and will be able to help you.